# AngularJS Error: Non-assignable model expression

Tags: angularjs

Saw this question asked a few times but I could not see how the answers applied to my problem. I keep receiving this error upon trying to upload a file.

`Error: Non-assignable model expression: undefined (directive: fileReader)`

How could I resolve it?

I've included all of the files that interact with each other, even though I am fairly certain the error occurs in fileDirective.js

**fileDirective.js. contains this directive:**

```
spreadsheetApp.directive('fileReader', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            file: '='
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        template: "<input type='file' onchange='angular.element(this).scope().upload(this)'>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.upload = function (element) {
                scope.$apply(function (scope) {
                    scope.file = element.files[0];
                });
            };

            scope.$watch('file', function () {
                if (scope.file) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = (function (file) {
                        return function (env) {
                            scope.$apply(function () {
                                scope.file.contents = env.target.result;
                            });
                        }
                    }(scope.file));
                    reader.readAsText(scope.file);
                }
            }, true);
        }
    };
});
```

(This was actually borrowed from [here](https://github.com/tombaaaaa/angularjs-textfilereader/blob/master/directives.js#L21).)

**index.html:**

```
<html ng-app="spreadsheetApp">
...
<ng-view></ng-view>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives/fileDirective.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/spreadsheetController.js"></script>
...
</html>
```

**app.js:**
    'use strict';

```
var spreadsheetApp = angular.module('spreadsheetApp',[]);

spreadsheetApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
        controller: 'spreadsheetController',
        templateUrl: 'views/innerHTML.html'
        });
});
```

And the contents of **innerHTML.html** are simply:
`<file-reader> </file-reader>`

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you have not defined that `fileReader` directive belongs to the correct module.

Try adding this top line:

```
    var spreadsheetApp = angular.module('spreadsheetApp');

    spreadsheetApp.directive('fileReader', function() {
        return {
            scope: {
                file: '='
            },
            restrict: 'E',
            template: "<input type='file' onchange='angular.element(this).scope().upload(this)'>",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
...
```

Or better yet:

```
 angular.module('spreadsheetApp').directive('fileReader', function() {
        return {
            scope: {
                file: '='
            },
            restrict: 'E',
            template: "<input type='file' onchange='angular.element(this).scope().upload(this)'>",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
...
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davintryon/Kc8VJ/) of a working file upload.

Comment: I just added a jsfiddle that works.  Check that out and try to adjust.

Answer (score 0):

Having the exact same issue, have a look at this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kc8VJ/1/ initialising the file attribute does the trick, but why is this necessary?

```
<div ng-app="spreadsheetApp" ng-init='fileOut=null'>
<file-reader file='fileOut'> </file-reader>
```

Answer (score 0):

The one thing, that is missing in your example, is a binding to some parent scope property:

```
<file-reader file="someParentScopeProperty"></file-reader>
```

What happened:

- The `file` property is defined with `'='`. In such case AngularJS tries to set up a bi-directional binding between this property and some parent scope property, of name defined via the `file` attribute.
- To define a parent scope property, it is enough to add the `file` attribute. The property    does not have to be initialized (no need for `ng-init`) nor explicitly declared.    AngularJS will create it for you.
- In your case the `file` attribute is missing, so the binding is not set up correctly. As a consequence, the first time you try to assign a value to the local property, you will get the 'Non-assignable' error. It happens in the line:

  ```
  scope.file = element.files[0];
  ```

Here you can find more on this topic: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile)